# Secure credit card form on our website in paypal

Tags: paypal, https, forms

Is it possible to encrypt our credit card information entered by user on my website's payment form?

```
<form method="post" action="/doDirect" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
Card Number:<br>
<input type="text" name="card_number"  placeholder="CARD NUMBER" id="ccnum" ><br>
First Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstName"  placeholder="FIRST NAME"><br>
Last Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastName"  placeholder="LAST NAME"><br>
Card Type:<br>
<select name="ctype" id="ctype" required="required">
<option value="visa">VISA</option>
<option value="master">MASTER</option>
<option value="maestro">MASTERO</option> 
<option value="americanexpress">AmericanExpress</option>
</select>
<br>
Expire Date:
<br>
<select name="exmonth" required="required">
<option value="">Month</option>
@for(i<-1 to 12){
@if(i<10){
<option value="0@i">0@i</option>
}else{
<option value="@i">@i</option>
}
}
</select>
/
<select name="exyear" required="required">
<option value="">Year</option>
@for(i<-1990 to 2033){
<option value="@i">@i</option>      
}
</select>   <br>
CVV2:<br>
<input type="text" name="cvv2" max="999" maxlength="3" required="required">
</div>
}
<input type="submit" value="Checkout" onclick="return isValidCreditCard()">
</form>
```

If we see, **Braintree** provides the *encryption javascripti* so then we won't get the real human readable entry.

**Braintree example to do so**

```
<h1>Braintree Credit Card Transaction Form</h1>
<div>
<form action="/create_transaction" method="POST" id="braintree-payment-form">
<p>
<label>Card Number</label>
<input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" data-encrypted-name="number" />
</p>
<p>
<label>CVV</label>
<input type="text" size="4" autocomplete="off" data-encrypted-name="cvv" />
</p>
<p>
<label>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</label>
          <input type="text" size="2" name="month" /> / <input type="text" size="4" name="year" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
```

And here is the Js

```
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v1/braintree.js"></script>
<script>
var braintree = Braintree.create('MIIBCgKCAQEA2ob0KfqpQ2xuy0zlq2a/amOuu0zkVdNHo45xSQVDErJEf2e/8rrAq40eh3C1sjm8DTFt8HLMvPDwi+nmOimuXQwdtkmszmMnJI5HLlvOCPyEgIxPgjKeyE3wzLOtDCMuQ3zKX2yU/v0rhqu4bng5knFoNLjjN6eet00u4Z5Jp84eDeZgevh1+Yb6Ca6P2iLQQherBupxmiKzAtImeyoeUoLDmBO68CFZd0rvxaKbUQ9yW+pHywpQrkSoQs9Z9J9W6HZ+w2YpYWmV0z2tJmYo8RvnKwyplFEC0EPZ+IPXJatcqQlTjQXhboXnCx2WZDQuVdzIRudmxLOM6m+hGetG1wIDAQAB');
braintree.onSubmitEncryptForm('braintree-payment-form');
</script>
```

Is there any way given by the **paypal** to encrytp the data using **JS** or any other tool?
Hope for the positive response

Answer (score 0):

Honest answer.

Don't.

Just ... don't.

PCI compliance is a nasty, hairy beast.

If you handle any Card Holder data, there is LOT that you have to do.

Most folks will "call out" to a credit card server provider who will handle the data then call your website back with a simple "accept/reject" code that you can then respond to.

For a quick overview, see:

http://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pcifaqs.php

Comment: I see your updated question.  Still can't do it and be PCI compliant.  In order to pass PCI compliance, encryption isn't enough.  There also have to be physical security on the web server that handles CardHolder data so that nobody can modify your Javascript and/or HTML and slip in code that will leak information out.  There is a lot more to cover than just data being moved around.

Comment: next updation, braintree is providing something like.. I'm still confused, it matters a lot, but still braintree is providing this kind of JS ..